# How to save SQLite3 work

Tags: database, sqlite, save

I've been playing with SQLite3 for a little bit, and I ended up inserting a lot of tables and data that I'd like to reuse later.

However, I don't see any way to save my data. I've searched online as well and couldn't find anything. I'm surprised nobody has asked this yet:

How can I save the tables and data I've created thus far?

Comment: Maybe this link can help: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/datamanipulation/

Comment: I assume if you installed the Sqlite on your computer, every database you create and every information you put in, should remain there. I dont quite understand the question. Is your data being removed somehow or what?

Comment: Are you using the sqlite3 REPL?

Answer (score 4):

When using the `sqlite3` command-line shell, you should specify a file name when starting it; otherwise, it will open a temporary database file.

If you forgot, you can open another database with the `.open` command.

If you forgot to do that before creating data, you can copy the database into another file with the `.backup` command.

Comment: I open SQLite3 shell by just clicking on it... where do I specify the file name?

Comment: You should not click on it; you should run it by typing `sqlite whatever.db` in the console.